# Why can't '#', '.', ':' be used in identifiers?

Tags: java, scjp

I understand why identifiers cannot start with numbers or '-'.

Why can't '#', '.' (point), and ':' (colon) be used as a part of an identifier?

Comment: Because your code would not compile? Note that numbers may be part of identifiers. I don't know where you got that rule from. Also, think about if dots could be part of identifiers. What would this code do: `foo.bar.baz.hello()`? would bar be a field of foo? or would foo.bar be a variable?

Comment: Because they are not allowed as they were not allowed in C which Java was based on.  In some cases they could have allowed `#` though it is reserved for future use but `.` and `:` have special meanings in Java.

Comment: Because The JLS Says So(tm)

Comment: yes you are correct JB Nizet , but why can't we use String foo.bar.baz.hello;

Comment: because when you would call `int length = foo.bar.baz.hello.length()`, you wouldn't know if `foo.bar.baz.hello` is a variable, or if `hello`is a field of `foo.bar.baz`, or if `baz.hello`is a field of `foo.bar`, etc. Even if the compiler were able to figure it out, it would make the code extremely hard to understand by humans. And code that is hard to understand is something you want to avoid at all cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Should not" is not and exact definition. Better use "must not" or "cannot".

Once we changed a question we can answer it. The reason is that this way the java programming language is defined. So, you can as "why did java creators defined such rules?"

There can be several answers. One of the most relevant (IMHO) is that all programming languages (at least those that I know) have more or less equal definition of what characters can be used in identifiers:

Letters, digits or underscore, starting from letter or underscore.

By the way java extends this rule because it permits to use any letter including national alphabets while typically other (at least older) programming languages restrict this to Latin letters only.

Among all characters that you wrote I think only `#` could be theoretically included into a list of characters permitted for identifiers but they decided not to do it probably thinking about future releases of java where *probably* this character will become a part of the language.

I think that usage of `,` and `;` in identifier is obviously impossible. Think about `for` operator.

Comment: Thank you i understood @AlexR , But why we should not use .(dot) ?

Comment: Do is even more obvious. How can you refer to field or method or object?

Comment: Thank you very much  Alex for your patience in answering my question(even though it looks silly).

Answer (score 1):

From the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8):

> An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java digits, **the first of which must be a Java letter**.
>
> ... A "Java letter" is a character for which the method `Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(int)` returns true.

Those aren't Java letters, so you can't start with those.  `$` *is*, but that usage is more reserved for inner classes.

Comment: I think the question is about why the JLS says you can't.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use any charecter that is reserved for JVM, which identifies those charecter as seprators delimters. it is basically the same thing as using "new" keyword as a name of a variable, which is illegal operation in Java.